# How can I collect information into an array of all checked checkboxes? Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a table that displays a list of users:

```
{{#each model.users as |user|}}
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>{{user.fullName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

I want to call an action that detects all of the checked checkboxes and puts those users emails into an array, ready to send an email to them. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use input helper for the checkbox as well you can connect the "checked" value to your store model.

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=user.selected}}
```

Then you can just loop through your users and check the "selected" property.